# Flushing pending ethereum transactions with ethers

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js, ether

I'm trying to work out how to clear a pending transaction with the ethers library.

It's ERC20 transfer function that's been called, several times, and quite a few stuck pending.

So, I thought I'd just be able to use ethers library to sendTransaction with the same nonce to flush the transactions.

What I've tried, assuming 100gwei;

```js
const tx = {
  gasPrice: ethers.BigNumber.from(100000000000),
  nonce: 1,
}

wallet.sendTransaction(tx)
```

Which results in `"err: max fee per gas less than block base fee: address xxx, maxFeePerGas: 100000000000 baseFee: 110470877095 (supplied gas 10440696)"}}'`.

Uncertain if I'm supposed to have a `to` in the transaction, and also... supplied gas, should I be adding a `gasLimit` to the transaction? Uncertain if `data` or `value` should contain anything, as cancelling a transaction is done with a 0 value right?

---

I accidentally cancelled the two first transactions instead by removing the gasPrice and just including the nonce. Damnit, now I have to figure out if I have to cancel all those after or if I can send in transactions with the same nonce.

Comment: Have you tried changing gasPrice to be something like:  `gasPrice:ethers.utils.parseUnits('100', 'gwei')`.  I think you are passing in too high of a gas price based on the error message.

Comment: I did, thanks! I still haven't managed to solve it, guessing it is gasLimit that I have to add `cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`... which I daren't do as the format confuses me

Comment: Ohhh I went for it with the gasLimit, was straightforward - I set it to 56000. Uncertain if I should have included the data field... reading source on this I feel like only the nonce and to address need to be the same for the network to pick it up as extra gas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I'm so annoyed at how search engine ranking has gone down the drain, all the articles I tried to look at were written by the creators of some wallet or other... I digress.

I seemed to read that adding `nonce` and `to` should be enough several times. Not enough. Just adding the nonce without anything cancels the transaction. `nonce`, `to`, `gasPrice` will complain about `gasLimit` as it can't work out how much gas a contract method needs (my case). Doing these will just result in a reverted transaction anyway as no data is sent.

So,

```
const tx = {
  to: {CONTRACT_ADDR},
  nonce: x,
  gasLimit: 58000 (just check what its consumed before and add some),
  gasPrice: ethers.utils.parsUnits('100', 'gwei')
  data: {TRANSACTION DATA IN HEX}
```

Celebrate.